expl3.sty reports version mismatch on Lualatex
background: This is a Linux distribution. I have system-wide installs of texlive from gentoo that I do not use. My texlive distribution is installed locally at ~/path/to/texlive.
I recently re-installed the complete texlive tree, and now get the following error:
    (~/path/to/texlive/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-07-20 L3 programming layer (loader) 


! LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX)        
(LaTeX)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX)        is dated 2024-01-22, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX)        at least 2024-07-20.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.78      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
                                       %

The cause seems to be an old format file in the user tree.
LaTeX found these files:
 - ~/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/lualatex.fmt 
 - /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luahbtex/lualatex.fmt 
Try deleting the file in the user tree then run LaTeX again.
LaTeX will abort loading the incompatible support files but this may lead to
later errors. Please ensure that your LaTeX format is correctly regenerated.

The thing is, neither of those files actually exists. I manually deleted the first, and uninstalled the system package that included the second.
So why is LaTeX still finding them and reporting a version mismatch?
UPDATE: I just deleted the directory ~/.texlive and recreated it as a symlink to my actual texlive installation path, and now it works without that error.
(ignore this, per comments below)

The files in the format are too old, so did you recreate the format?

you mean you deleted ~/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/lualatex.fmt ? latex would not report that there if it isn't unless it is running under a different account with a different ~

@UlrikeFischer: I did not recreate them. How do I do that for a local installation?
@DavidCarlisle: yes, that's the file I deleted. It's not there when I use ls in that directory. But LaTeX still reports it as being there.

I don't know what type of installation you have. On windows I always run only fmtutil-sys --byfmt lualatex or fmtutil-sys --all

@UlrikeFischer: As far as I'm aware fmtutil-sys --all will generate .fmt files for the system install, not a local install. fmtutil-user will do it for a local install, but that still doesn't generate those files, and they still don't exist.

you should use fmtutil-sys  (using -user previously was the cause of the issue) that will update the ~/path/to/texlive installation, it will not touch the separate linux-installed installation

Please do not edit solutions in to the question, post a separate answer post if you wish (but symlinking ~/.texlive is not the correct solution and may lead to conflicts later.

You should remove the symlink ~/.texlive.

OK, I've removed the symlink, and documents still seem to compile. So now I should run fmutil-sys --all? Or is that a necessary step at this point?

So, I can't run the command fmtutil-sys --all without root privileges, which strongly suggests to me that it will change my system installation, not my local one. Or am I missing something here? Furthermore, I'm not getting errors in my log that luaotfload can't save the cache or write the db, and I'm getting ugly formatting script in my document output. So what's going on here?

"Furthermore, I'm not…" → "Furthermore, I'm now…"
I'm getting an error Font \TU/AtkinsonHyperlegible(0)/m/it/9=name:Atkinson not loadable: metric data not found or bad., which appears at two parts of the awesome-cv class I'm working on (both with italics). In the document, it shows the following: Hyperlegible/I:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt; at 9.0pt right before a block of italic text. So what's it failing to interpret correctly, and how do I fix it?
